# how to change columns order in jenkins open source project?

Tags: xml, git, github, jenkins

I want to suggest an improvement to "jenkins" Git project.

I want to change the order of the columns in the main page:

[image]

I opened the GitHub project and searched for "

Two things:

1) Why couldn't I find a `view.xml` in the search box of my new branch?

Even though I could navigate to this `view.xml` manually.

page:

```
https://github.com/elad2109/hudson/edit/master/test/src/test/resources/hudson/cli/view.xml
```

searches:

```
https://github.com/elad2109/hudson/edit/master/test/src/test/resources/hudson/cli/view.xml

https://github.com/elad2109/hudson/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=view.xml
```

2) I thought to edit this page `view.xml` just to change the order of:

```
  <columns>
    <hudson.views.StatusColumn/>
    <hudson.views.WeatherColumn/>
    <hudson.views.BuildButtonColumn/>
    <hudson.views.JobColumn/>
    <hudson.views.LastSuccessColumn/>
    <hudson.views.LastFailureColumn/>
    <hudson.views.LastDurationColumn/>
```

but then I wonder - why is this under `test` folder?

---

I was answered that column order can be changed.

But I'm still interested in my questions about searching and editing in GitHub and jenkins-GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to modify Jenkins since this feature was implemented long ago.

You need to create a new view and then you can drag / drop the columns.

See this [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Changing+the+Columns+of+a+View) for more details

Comment: Thanks. Only the owner of an existing view can change this?

Comment: can you relate to my questions anyway? Im new to git hub searching and editing

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jenkins source structure but usually stuff under `test` are used for testing.

That `view.xml` seems to be used as a `testing resource` in order to manipulate the views when using Jenkins `CLI`.

Comment: how can I suggest a new order as a default order? I'm not sure